# Asigning variables for individual elements in a row

Tags: c++

i'm a quite unexperienced c++ user and i've recently encountered a problem. I need to write a script that would operate on given input. Input is a coordinate file including 108 rows with 4 records in each row. First record is always a letter, specifying the element and the other three records are three numbers of equivalent length, representing x y and z components, with blank space fs, like this:

```
O      4.972407     6.001956     6.766559
O     -1.537917     5.179561     5.602830
.....
```

My script should extract certain rows and print them in some output file. This i've already done using while, if and getline, like this:

```
if (myfile.is_open())
{
   int line_no = 1;  
   while (line_no <= 108 && getline(myfile,line)) {
     line_no++;  
     if (line_no == 19) {
       getline (myfile,line);  
       cout << line << '\n';  
     }
     else if (line_no == 59) {
      getline (myfile,line);  
      cout << line << '\n';  
     }
     else if (line_no == 60) {
      getline (myfile,line);  
      cout << line << '\n';  
     }
     else if (line_no == 87) {
       getline (myfile,line);  
       cout << line << '\n';  
     }
     else if (line_no == 102) {  
       getline (myfile,line);  
       cout << line << '\n';   
     }
  }
  myfile.close();
}
```

The lines extracted have to be in precise order, so i've had to include 17 of those with 17 line strings. It get pretty extensive and i'm sure there should be an easier way to do this. I would appreciate any suggestions and ideas.

Now the real problem comes when i actually get the output file. I need to assign a variable for each number in a row, in order to put them inside a formula. I tried doing this using array, like this:

```
const int SIZE = 60;  
double grades[SIZE];  

void readData() {
  string inFileName = "out.txt";  
  ifstream inFile;   
  inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());  

  if (inFile.is_open())
  {   
     for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)  
     {  
        inFile >> grades[i];  
        cout << grades[i] << " ";  
     }  

     inFile.close(); // CLose input file  
  }  
  else { //Error message   
    cerr << "Can't find input file " << inFileName << endl;  
  }
}
```

but i think there must be a problem with every fourth element being a letter. The output is get:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I'd appreciate any ideas, corrections, suggestions that would improve my script.

---

**[edit]**

About the first part. I have a coordinate file and i need to extract specific lines in sets of five, like this:

```
P     -3.070974     5.319084     5.505385   
O     -3.375664     6.157090     4.244211  
O      4.972407     6.001956     6.766559  
O     -1.537917     5.179561     5.602830   
O      4.900104     3.921648     5.407940  
P      3.070979     4.630705     1.835121   
O      3.644369     3.947834     0.573947 ....
```

I cannot do it using just one while cycle cause it will print out lines according to their initial position. So, likewise i wrote 17 while loops like the one i showed to print out 17 sets. Any suggestions?

Input file looks like this:

```
P      6.783213     2.487446     1.835121   
P     -2.474827     4.974898    20.186419  
P      2.474819     4.974898     9.175649   
P      1.237407     7.118158    20.186419  
P     -1.237416     2.831639     9.175649  
P      1.237407     2.831639    20.186419   
P     -1.237416     7.118158     9.175649   
P      5.545802     0.344186    12.845891    
P      5.545802     4.630705    12.845891   
P      1.833567     2.487446    12.845891    
P      2.474823     0.000000    16.516155    
P      3.070974     5.319084    16.516155   
P     -1.237412     2.143260    16.516155     
O     -0.664021     1.460388    15.254981   
O      4.972412     1.027057    14.107065    
O      3.375664     6.157090    15.254981     
O      5.241113     3.792699    14.107065     
O     -2.711642     7.307209    15.254981     
O      2.711646     2.642580    14.107065    
O      1.596740     5.130033    10.436823     
O     -1.596748     4.819764    18.925245     
O     -0.664026     3.514510    10.436823     
O      0.664017     6.435287    18.925245
```

and on and on.

I know the atoms i need, that means i know the line i need to extract, thats all. So all i wanted to ask, is there any way to improve my script?

Comment: The code you show is not your real code and thus doesn't replicate the issue you have. Please try to create a [mcve] to show us, one that replicates the problem and that hopefully we can copy-paste and try ourselves. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Thanks :D but i think my problem is really general, i don't think i even need to show any code for you to realise it

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you studying a particular configuration of NaTi2(PO4)3 and interested in the positions of only some of the atoms?

Comment: Thank you so much, this site is really quite awesome! Yeah, i think im calculating the states as the functional of electron density... or that's how they say it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning your second part :

> ```
>  double grades[SIZE];  
>  ...
>  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)  
>  {  
>      inFile >> grades[i];  
>      cout << grades[i] << " ";  
>  }
> ```

because

> First record is always a letter

the very first `inFile >> grades[i];` will not success (a letter like 'O' is not a valid float representation) and *inFiLe* will be on error and none of the next `>>` will do something too.

So *grades* is not set in the *for* and you always prints the default value 0 coming from the initialization of your global array.

If you want to memorize the doubles you have to also read the letter, so to read a letter (maybe through a string whatever) then 3 double then again a letter etc

I encourage you to check if each read success to detect an invalid file, including a premature EOF

so for instance :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

const int SIZE = 60;  
double grades[SIZE];  

void readData() {
  string inFileName = "out.txt";  
  ifstream inFile;   
  inFile.open(inFileName.c_str());  // only old C++ version does not accept std::string and required the c_str

  if (inFile.is_open())
  {   
    string s; // to read 2 letters like Ti in your input after edition

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)  
    {  
      if ((i % 3) == 0) {
        if (! (inFile >> s)) {
          cerr << endl << "error when reading letter(s) line " << (i/3)+1 << endl;
          return;
        }
      }

      if (! (inFile >> grades[i])) {
        cerr << endl << "error when reading the " << i+1 << " nth double" << endl;
        return;
      }
      cout << grades[i] << " ";  
    }  

    cout << endl;

    inFile.close(); // CLose input file  
  }  
  else { //Error message   
    cerr << "Can't find input file " << inFileName << endl;  
  }  
}

int main()
{
  readData();
}
```

Compilation and execution (with a too short file) :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic v.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat out.txt 
O      4.972407     6.001956     6.766559
O     -1.537917     5.179561     5.602830
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
4.97241 6.00196 6.76656 -1.53792 5.17956 5.60283 
error when reading letter line 3
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note in your way to do you do not return the number of double you read, you cannot distinguish the final 0 from the ones set by the initialization.

It is also much more practical to use a `std::vector<double>` rather than an array, that avoid the limitation on the size and you can get the size from the vector rather than separately .

---

Concerning the first part of your question warning `line_no` does *not* indicate the rank of the line you read because each time one of the *if* is true you read a line without updating `line_no`.

From your additional information :

> I know the atoms i need, that means i know the line i need to extract, thats all. So all i wanted to ask, is there any way to improve my script?

Your code is equivalent to that one, more clear and small :

```
if (myfile.is_open())
{
   static const int lineToWrite[] = { 19, 60, 62, 90, 106, -1 };
   const int * p = lineToWrite;
   int line_no = 0;  

   while (line_no <= 108 && getline(myfile,line)) {
     if (++line_no == *p) {
       cout << line << '\n';  
       p += 1;
     }
  }
  myfile.close();
}
```

But because the second line you want to write is

```
O     -3.375664     6.157090     4.244211
```

so 59 in your code is wrong and the second number in my proposal must be replaced by 39 (the expected line is the 39nth numbering the first line 1)

```
if (myfile.is_open())
{
   static const int lineToWrite[] = { 19, 39, 62, 90, 106, -1 };
   const int * p = lineToWrite;
   int line_no = 0;  

   while (line_no <= 108 && getline(myfile,line)) {
     if (++line_no == *p) {
       cout << line << '\n';  
       p += 1;
     }
  }
  myfile.close();
}
```

That writes the lines

```
P -3.070974 5.319084 5.505385
O 3.375664 6.157090 15.254981
```

Perhaps `62, 90, 106` are wrong too but the set you give do not contains the expected lines from the third so I cannot check/correct

Comment: First, thank you so much for taking your time, i think it's gonna be a lot easier from now on!

Comment: @kazimierastamoliunas are the rank of the lines to extract (write) statically known ? You code is strange because you compare with 19 to extract the line 20, and to 59 to extract the line 61 etc, and that because of the redundant getlines introducing a shift in the rank

Comment: if by rank you mean the line number, then yes, but they are not sequential in my initial input file

Comment: i mean there is no logical sequence, i still have to physically write the linenumber in order to extract it. I was just wondering maybe its possible to do it with 1 while loop instead of 17

Comment: @kazimierastamoliunas I do not understand, line number are sequential, may be the distances between line to output are not the same in all case but whatever

Comment: @kazimierastamoliunas if you are able to put the line number to extract through  literal int there is a more simple way, I will edit my answer ...

Comment: @kazimierastamoliunas I edited it, read it again, not your code does't allow to get the line `O     -3.375664     6.157090     4.244211` because 59 is your code is wrong

Comment: @Bob__ yes, even not sure this is the same input file you are right it is better to suppose that, I edited my answer to read a word (string) rather than just a character

Comment: Thanks a lot kind @Bruno, you helped me a whole lot here!!

Comment: These codes are working when i use them separately. However, whenether i try to combine them, either in the same file or using headers i can never reach the same result and always get error "error when reading letter(s) line" with the value of one. Can somebody please assist me with that? Im completely out of ideas...

Comment: @kazimierastamoliunas which codes ? with what changes if from your question / my answer ? As you see in my answer I said some indexes are wrong but I was't able to change them because of not enough inputs

Comment: Ok take a look at your answer. You helped to improve and solve both 1st and 2nd parts of a script. So that's how i was intending to use them. First i extract specific lines, then i get rid of letters and get a number sequence/array. Both are working perfectly, but i just don't know how to combine them properly. Do i put function definition in header file, include header file in main.cpp and then include readData() at the end of main() function block? Do i need to initialise the function somewhere? I tried all of those actually but nothing seems to work

Comment: @kazimierastamoliunas the header files are the place to _declare_ functions, not to _define_ them, the function definitions must be placed in source file. If you do not want to put all in the same source file just put them in several and compile / link all of them to produce the executable. I do not understand what you mean by _initialise the function_, variables can be initialized, not functions. What means _but nothing seems to work_, what problem do you have ? Probably the best you have to do is to open a new question